# Spring Integration : Http Request -> Response -> Process -> If more data available -> Loop and Repeat until no data received

Tags: spring-integration

I have to query an http endpoint with offset and limit until no more data exist. For example,

> **POST 1** -> {"offset" : 0, "limit" : 50} : Returned 50 records -> continue to poll next offset

> **POST 2** -> {"offset" : 50, "limit" : 50} : Returned 25 records -> stop polling (25 < limit, so no more records)

How can I implement this loop with dynamic request body {"offset" : a, "limit" : b} using Service Activator and HTTP Outbound Gateway in spring-integration?
I looked at Polling Consumer and Adding Behavior to endpoints [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain) in the docs

One option is to add the loop logic in Service Activator and use a Gateway to bring the message into the channel.

Is there a better way of doing this including error handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop could be done with the `router` component. So, you do some processing logic then forward message to the router to determine if you need to call an HTTP gateway again and just send a message with an appropriate `offset` in the payload or headers.

So, with pseudo code it may look like this:

send message with offset 0 -> httpInputChannel -> HTTP gateway -> process -> router.

The route function should decide to send a new offset back to the httpInputChannel or exit to the next channel.

See router component: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

The error handling could be done with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on that HTTP outbound gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice